# How to use a variable for a table column reference

Tags: excel, variables, syntax, reference

I have the following syntax to reference the data body range of the column 'Role' in the table 'Users';

[Users[Role]]

My question is how to modify the this syntax if the column was captured in a variable?

I've tried the following but it isn't working:

```
Dim colX as string
[Users[colX]]
[Users[ & colX & ]]
```

Comment: Are you adding a formula to the table?

Comment: @-BigBen, nope.

Comment: If you're not adding a formula, then I would expect something like `ListObjects("Users").ListColumns(colx)`.

Comment: @-BigBen, thanks. I've tried that method and it works just fine but I was looking to use the above style of syntax which is much shorter. I'm just bemused as to why it isn't handling variables.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with more code? Presumably the `"[Users["` and closing `"]]"` should be like that, in quotes.

Comment: @-BigBen. Don't think any of my specific code would add much value. I'm simply trying to loop through a couple of defined table columns using an array of strings. It's definitely working if I do the complete reference i.e. using worksheet.listobject.listcolumn etc. But I'm purely just interested in this shorter syntax style.   FYI - as per your last comment, "[Users[" & colX & "]]" doesn't work either even if I surround it with range("[Users[" & colX & "]]").select

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you are using and how it's not working (note that you almost never need to `Select`)

Comment: Try `Range("Users[" & colx & "]")`.

Comment: @-BigBen Thanks. Yeah, I'm aware that 'Select' is rarely required. I'm just using it to test usage of this syntax which is why you don't need to see all of my code. This is evidenced by the fact that your answer (___Range("Users[" & colx & "]")___) works perfectly! Thanks very much :)